# Interpreting results of Libreoffice Calc's TTEST function

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, excel

I'm doing some data analysis on a small dataset (35 individuals) and I'm wondering whether my findings are statistically significant. Individuals are asked questions before and after a treatment, so it's a paired dataset.

Therefore, I've put the data in Libreoffice Calc and applied the TTEST function. Unfortunately, the information online about this function is really sparse. The [docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Statistical_Functions_Part_Five#TTEST) say "Returns the probability associated with a Student's t-Test.", but I can't find any examples how to interpret this value.

Am I right in assuming that the returned value is the probabilty that the null hypothesis is true (p-value). I.e. a TTEST value 0.0011 would mean that there is a 0.11 % chance that the treatment wasn't actually helping, but the results are just random?

I'm looking for an answer that is specific for Libreoffice Calc's TTEST function.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Screenshot 1]

[Dataset 1](http://pastebin.com/r1zs8MuN) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5NG.png) [Dataset 2](http://pastebin.com/ZNnYziZu)

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests is related, but it does not answer my question what Libreoffice Calc's TTEST actually returns. The result is /not/ a t-value (that I could look up in a t-table with DF=34), it is a probability.

Comment: It seems to me that LibreOffice Calc's TTEST returns the p-value. I used data from an [example data set](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf) and TTEST's value matched the p-value mentioned there (p = 0.004). [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/CqL5O01)